# Etymology of the word "σκευή"

Tags: greek, etymology

What's the origin of the word "σκευή"? Is it Indo-European?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be unknown. Here's Beekes on the family of σκεῦος (which includes σκευή):

[image]

Chantraine has nothing useful to add (for once).

Comment: Good answer! You might also add that _skeyē_ is just _skeyos_ with a feminine noun ending added.